# Jasper Report Crosstab with ArrayList of Data

Tags: jasper-reports

I am trying to create Jasper Report with crosstab by writing JRXML with DTOs.

I am trying to create rows dynamic number of chargeCodes and their total. It looks something like this:

| jobNo | chargeCodeA | chargeCodeB | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| jobNoABC | 100.10 | 300.30 | 400.40 |
| jobNoDEF | 200.20 | 400.40 | 600.60 |

In my Java backend, I have DTO which looks like this

```
class MyDTO {
private String jobNo;
private List <String> chargeCode = new ArrayList <> ();
private List <BigDecimal> chargeCodeTotal = new ArrayList <> ();
}
```

where the list codeCode contains chargeCodeA, chargeCodeB for jobNoABC

and chargeCodeTotal contains 100.10, 300.30 for jobNoABC also.

In my JRXML, I have this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"  ?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd"
        name="vendorBillingCompletedJobReport" leftMargin="5" rightMargin="5">
    
    <parameter name="lblJobNo" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false"/>
    
    <field name="jobNo" class="java.lang.String"/>
    
    <field name="chargeCode" class="java.util.List"/>
    <field name="chargeCodeTotal" class="java.util.List"/>
  <summary>
    <band height="60">
      <crosstab>
        <reportElement width="782" y="0" x="0" height="60" />
        <rowGroup name="jobNo" width="100" totalPosition="End">
          <bucket>
            <bucketExpression class="java.util.List">
              <![CDATA[$F{jobNo}]]>
            </bucketExpression>
          </bucket>
          <crosstabRowHeader>
            <cellContents>
              <box>
                <pen lineColor="black" lineWidth="1"/>
              </box>
              <textField>
                <reportElement width="100" y="0" x="0" height="20" />
                <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle" />
                <textFieldExpression>
                  <![CDATA[$V{jobNo}]]>
                </textFieldExpression>
              </textField>
            </cellContents>
          </crosstabRowHeader>
          <crosstabTotalRowHeader>
            <cellContents>
              <box>
                <pen lineColor="black" lineWidth="1"/>
              </box>
              <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="20" />
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle" />
                <text>TOTAL</text>
              </staticText>
            </cellContents>
          </crosstabTotalRowHeader>
        </rowGroup>
        <columnGroup name="chargeCode" height="20" totalPosition="End">
          <bucket>
            <bucketExpression class="java.util.List">
              $F{chargeCode}
            </bucketExpression>
          </bucket>
          <crosstabColumnHeader>
            <cellContents>
              <box>
                <pen lineColor="black" lineWidth="1"/>
              </box>
              <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement width="60" y="0" x="0" height="20" />
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Bottom" />
                <textFieldExpression>
                  <![CDATA[$V{chargeCode}]]>
                </textFieldExpression>
              </textField>
            </cellContents>
          </crosstabColumnHeader>
          <crosstabTotalColumnHeader>
            <cellContents>
              <box>
                <pen lineColor="black" lineWidth="1"/>
              </box>
              <staticText>
                <reportElement width="60" y="0" x="0" height="20" />
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Bottom" />
                <text>TOTAL</text>
              </staticText>
            </cellContents>
          </crosstabTotalColumnHeader>
        </columnGroup>
        <measure name="chargeCodeTotalCount" class="java.math.BigDecimal" calculation="Sum">
          <measureExpression>$F{chargeCodeTotal}</measureExpression>
        </measure>
        <crosstabCell height="20" width="60">
          <cellContents backcolor="#FFFFFF">
            <box>
              <pen lineColor="black" lineWidth="1"/>
            </box>
            <textField>
              <reportElement x="5" y="0" width="55" height="20" />
              <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Bottom" />
              <textFieldExpression class="java.math.BigDecimal">
                $V{chargeCodeTotalCount}
              </textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
          </cellContents>
        </crosstabCell>
      </crosstab>
    </band>
  </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

But I am getting error:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable
> at org.apache.commons.collections.comparators.ComparableComparator.compare(ComparableComparator.java:91)

I am not sure how to create infinite number of chargeCodes using JRXML.

And I cannot use Dynamic Jasper. I can only think of crosstab. Please help. Thanks.